# Child theme css not loading when declared in parent functions

Tags: child-theme

This code exists in the parent theme functions to load the child theme styles if the file exists but it is not loading at all even though the `theme.css` file is present in the child theme `assets` directory. The child theme is working otherwise.

```
/**
 *
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 */
function nokul_editor_styles() {
    // Add the child theme CSS if it exists.
    if ( file_exists( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/assets/theme.css' ) ) {
        add_editor_style(
            '/assets/theme.css'
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'nokul_editor_styles' );
```

Am I missing something with this? Does the stylesheet have to be enqueued in the child theme functions still...?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're using a subfolder path that starts with a `/`.

The official WP.org developer doc for `add_editor_style` has an example of how to add a stylesheet from a subfolder in the comments:

```php
/**
 * Registers an editor stylesheet in a sub-directory.
 */
function add_editor_styles_sub_dir() {
    add_editor_style( trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'css/editor-style.css' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'add_editor_styles_sub_dir' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_editor_style/#comment-2730

Comment: Ah this is interesting to learn but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. I've even tried a direct copy and paste of the code you referenced and it doesn't try to load that editor-style.css file. It's like `add_editor_style` isn't working at all but `add_theme_support( 'editor-styles' );` is declared in the functions.

Comment: @zigojacko Are you using the block editor or the classic editor?

Comment: @JacobPeattie block editor and FSE

Comment: did you change the `css/editor-style.css` part? Are there are 404's in the dev console when loading the editor? Have you tried `wp_die( $the CSS URL so you can double check it )`? And that the file you're using isn't in a PHP namespace?

Comment: and how are you testing if this does/doesn't work?